# stop observables in Observable.zip while empty response comes

Tags: angular, typescript, reactive

I am working on angular  and Typescript. I have one code like

```
const activePairs = Observable
    .zip(ActiveCustomerChoices, ActiveLocations)
    .map(([ccs, locs]) => makePairs(ccs, locs));
```

but  `ActiveCustomerChoices` may return empty data. If it does, I need to extract it and stop the execution. How can I stop observables?

Comment: take a look into `takeUntil` and you might use it like take until active customer choices return something empty

Comment: I have given codes like const activePairs = Observable
    .zip(ActiveCustomerChoices, ActiveLocations).takUntil(Observable.of([])
    .map(([ccs, locs]) => makePairs(ccs, locs)); But stops the executions but not working for valid response also can you please give a demo code for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `takeWhile`

```
const activePairs = ActiveCustomerChoices
    .takeWhile(ccs => ccs.length > 0)
    .zip(ActiveLocations)
    .map(([ccs, locs]) => makePairs(ccs, locs))
```

Comment: superb i got it..Thanks buddies